# jQuery show is not working

Tags: jquery

I am stuck with the below issue, where jQuery `show()` function is not intermittently working.

`errorDiv` is hide by default(during on load), when user hits the Enter student button, I want to show the error message, And on mouseout event, I will hide the `errorDiv` and display it if user hits the 'Enter student' button again.

When I set the breakpoint on `show()` function, it works. But if I test it outside debugger, it is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#enter').click(function(){        
    alert('show');
  $('#defaultError').text("Incorrect entry");  
  $('.errorDiv').delay(2000).show();
 });
 
  $('#enter').mouseout(function (){
    alert('hide');
  $('.errorDiv:visible').hide();
 });
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row.align-left">
 <div class="small-7">
  <div class="errorDiv">
   <label id="defaultError" name="defaultError" class="error"></label>
  </div>
    <div class="testDiv">
   <label id="test" name="test" class="error">Test Entry</label>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<button class="button" role="button" id="enter" name="enter" type="button">
     <i class="fi-plus large">Enter student</i>
</button>
```

Comment: The user clicks on the button, and it starts to show the DIV, but as soon as the user moves the mouse away from the button, it hides the DIV.

Comment: Could you turn the code in the question into an executable [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: The brackets in your Javascript aren't balanced properly.

Comment: `$('errorDiv').delay(2000)` doesn't do anything. `.delay()` can only be use after you've queued an asynchronous operation on an element.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct. mouseout() event is fired immediately after the click on the button. The idea is not show this error message in the page permanently, as it will not have a good user experience.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` to hide the error a few seconds later.

Comment: Thanks. I have used setTimeout() to hide the error.

Answer (score 0):

i think its a small syntax error..please replace your click function code with this one

```
   $('#enter').click(function(){
     $('#defaultError').text("Incorrect entry");     
     $('.errorDiv').delay(2000).show();
   });
```

Updated fiddle: [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8z804ank/)

Comment: It's probably a copying error, because the syntax error would prevent all of the code from running.

Comment: have you seen my updated fiddle?..its working correclty i guess

Comment: Also just try simple steps like  $('.errorDiv').show(); and  $('.errorDiv').hide(); . I dont think delay(2000) and $('.errorDiv:visible').hide(); does anything extra

Answer (score 0):

Try folowing code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).off('click', '#enter').on('click', '#enter', function(){
   $('#defaultError').text("Incorrect entry");     
   $('.errorDiv').delay(2000).show();
});

$(document).off('mouseout', '#enter').on('mouseout', '#enter', function (){
   $('.errorDiv:visible').hide();
});

}
```

Comment: Explain what his problem was, and how your changed code fixes it. Don't just dump a bunch of code and say "try this"